# Xcode 12 Source control -> .gitignore file

Tags: xcode, git, image, gitignore

I'm trying to ignore all images from my project.

I have a .gitignore file in the root directory where the project file is located. I created this file with "touch .gitignore" then I applied a generated input from https://www.gitignore.io with the keywords swift and xcode. After that I applied below the "Others" comment following pattern

*.png
*.imageasset

to ignore all images.

For specific folders and files it works, the source control in xcode doesnt show me this files anymore for a commit, but the images will always shown. I also tried to block a image through the Preferences -> Source Control -> Git -> Ignore files, but it didnt worked.

**By the way**
The image files are not in my repository, I have never committed them.

The .gitignore file:

```
# Created by https://www.gitignore.io/api/swift,xcode

### Swift ###
# Xcode
#
# gitignore contributors: remember to update Global/Xcode.gitignore, Objective-C.gitignore & Swift.gitignore

## Build generated
build/
DerivedData/

## Various settings
*.pbxuser
!default.pbxuser
*.mode1v3
!default.mode1v3
*.mode2v3
!default.mode2v3
*.perspectivev3
!default.perspectivev3
xcuserdata/

## Other
*.moved-aside
*.xccheckout
*.xcscmblueprint
*.png
*.imageasset

## Obj-C/Swift specific
*.hmap
*.ipa
*.dSYM.zip
*.dSYM

## Playgrounds
timeline.xctimeline
playground.xcworkspace

# Swift Package Manager
#
# Add this line if you want to avoid checking in source code from Swift Package Manager dependencies.
# Packages/
# Package.pins
.build/

# CocoaPods - Refactored to standalone file

# Carthage - Refactored to standalone file

# fastlane
#
# It is recommended to not store the screenshots in the git repo. Instead, use fastlane to re-generate the
# screenshots whenever they are needed.
# For more information about the recommended setup visit:
# https://docs.fastlane.tools/best-practices/source-control/#source-control

fastlane/report.xml
fastlane/Preview.html
fastlane/screenshots
fastlane/test_output

### Xcode ###
# Xcode
#
# gitignore contributors: remember to update Global/Xcode.gitignore, Objective-C.gitignore & Swift.gitignore

## Build generated

## Various settings

## Other

### Xcode Patch ###
*.xcodeproj/*
!*.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj
!*.xcodeproj/xcshareddata/
!*.xcworkspace/contents.xcworkspacedata
/*.gcno

# End of https://www.gitignore.io/api/swift,xcode
```

Comment: I’m not sure which problem you’re trying to solve but I’m pretty sure removing all images from git but not from your project is not the answer. If you tell us what you’re trying to achieve we might be able to help you find a better solution.

Comment: @EmilioPelaez The OP wants git to ignore the image files in their project.

Comment: Yeah, I obviously get that, but next time OP clones the project it will most likely fail to compile, at best it will launch without any image assets at all.

Answer (score 2):

If git was tracking the image files before you added the .gitignore file, it will continue to track them after adding the .gitignore file. You have to remove the image files from the git repository, commit the changes, and add the image files back to your project to ignore the image files.

I recommend backing up your project and creating a new branch before you attempt to remove the image files from the git repository.